# SQL NOT EXIST returning duplicate value in query results

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, not-exists

Hi Seem to be getting duplicates from this sql code it suppose to find records on ***BO Data*** that is not on ***Order Data*** by using the following as a key ***Keyorderstatus*** all my query results are on the ***Order Data*** already, How can a remedy this issue?

```
SELECT Keyorderstatus, 
OrderNumber, 
PartsNo, 
HoldType, 
ShiptoCode, 
BackOrderQty, 
OrderStatusCode
FROM [BO Data]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM [BO Data]
                  WHERE [BO Data].Keyorderstatus = [Order Data].Keyorderstatus
                 ) 
AND [BO Data].OrderStatusCode="AWAITING_SHIPPING"
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM [Order Data]
                WHERE Keyorderstatus IS NULL);
```

Comment: This is going to be tough since we have no idea what your data looks like. Try throwing a DISTINCT just after your SELECT if you are looking to remove dupes.

Comment: This line: `WHERE [BO Data].Keyorderstatus = [Order Data].Keyorderstatus` uses the table [Order Data], but this table is not included in same `select`, it will duplicate data

Comment: The 2nd `NOT EXISTS` is not correlated? And the 1st should return an eror message, because it's using a column from a different table.

Comment: Hi thank you for the rapid responses  @dfundako where would i use the DISTINCT in that code.

Comment: @RicardoPontual how could i correct this code in a way that it will only bring me back the correct data?

Comment: @ASTRIX285 Leave your code the same but use SELECT DISTINCT instead at the top.
Also, please look at the other comments about your exists statements.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Thank you for that amendment it works super, i found out the reason it was duplicating the records in the query originally i was asking it to check " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM [BO Data]' it should have been '[Order Data]' instead and that fix all my issue, appreciate all the advise on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dfundako said - hard to check without data tables to test against.

I'm thinking this SQL should do what you're after:

```
SELECT        [BO Data].KeyOrderStatus
            , OrderNumber
            , PartsNo
            , HoldType
            , ShipToCode
            , BackOrderQty
            , [BO Data].OrderStatusCode
FROM        [BO Data] LEFT JOIN [Order Data] ON [BO Data].KeyOrderStatus <> [Order Data].KeyOrderStatus
WHERE       [BO Data].OrderStatusCode = 'AWAITING SHIPPING'
GROUP BY    [BO Data].KeyOrderStatus
            , [BO Data].OrderStatusCode
```

Checking `[Order Data].KeyOrderStatus IS NULL` may not be necessary as (I'm assuming) `[BO Data].KeyOrderStatus` is a Primary Key so it must always contain a value and the SQL checks if that's different from the value in [Order Data] - if it's NULL it will be different from the PK.

Edit:  I've added in the other fields not relevant to the joins.  You'll have to group on these to.